# Get multiple Drop down menu Data using POST in NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, html-select, ejs

I have multiple Drop down menus and have a single button that posts all the data, like

[image: this].

But I am getting undefined on using `req.body.stringdata`:

[image: screenshot]

Here are the

[image: route page] and the

[image: form page]

How can I receive the data?

Comment: you're using `POST` method , right ? In your code, you have used `GET` to handle the request.

Comment: it was just to see what data we were getting

Comment: This will give a better understanding on how to get data via `POST`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: i already saw and tried to implement this. but it still gives undefined in the console

Comment: Can you provide your `form` code and how you're handing it.

Comment: Edited. please check the question for form page.

Comment: Try logging out `req.query['stringdata'])`, since it is a `GET` method.

Comment: thank you sir. it works. one last question, will it work on post too ?

Comment: For `POST` method, you will have to change the method in your form to `POST` and while handling the request you'll use `req.body.stringdata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data, use `req.query['stringdata'])` as the method used is `GET`.